# Nextjs Graphql Strapi Dynamic routes error

Tags: javascript, react, next.js, graphql, helper

Bom dia estou tentando fazer uma card com um link que crie uma rota Dinamica o nextjs usando apollo client e graphql, ja tentei varias coisas e recebo o mesmo error sempre:

Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for.

**Esta é minha query que estou usando para pegar as paginas por slug dinamicamente**

```
const GET_CARD_BY_SLUG = gql `
query GET_CARD_SLUG($slug:String){
    cards(filters:{slug:{contains:$slug}}){
      data{
        attributes{
          titulo
          slug
          description
          valor
          image{
            data{
              attributes{url}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
`
```

** Essa é minha pagina [slug].js**

```
import GET_CARD_BY_SLUG from "../../lib/queries/getRoupasBySlug"
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

import { initializeApollo } from "../../lib/apollo"
import GET_CARDS from "../../lib/queries/getRoupas"

const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

export default function Index({card}){
const router = useRouter()
if(router.isFallback)return null
 return (
     <h1>{card.titulo}</h1>
        )

}


export async function getStaticProps({params}){
 const {data} = await apolloClient.query({query:GET_CARD_BY_SLUG, variables:{slug:`${params?.slug}`}})

const card = data.cards
console.log('card', card)
return{
 props:{
     revalidate:60,
     card
    
 }
}

}

export async function getStaticPaths(){
 const {data} = await apolloClient.query({query:GET_CARDS})
 const paths = data.cards.data.map(({slug})=>({
     params:{slug: data.cards.data}
 }))

 return{ paths, fallback:false}
    
}
```

*estou a um bom tempo tentando resolver esta situação, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria muito mesmo!*